# Azure VPN point-to-site Client Connection Not Connecting

Tags: vpn, azure, vpn-client, point-to-site-vpn

I have downloaded the VPN Client zip file from azure. I have managed to install it, but When I try to connect to the VPN, I get the error “A certificate could not be found that can be used with this Extensible Authentication Protocol. (Error 798)”.

I have tried [these instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-troubleshoot-vpn-point-to-site-connection-problems), but installing the certificate doesn’t seem to create any certificates in the certificate store and it still doesn’t connect.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are missing all the correct certificates according to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-troubleshoot-vpn-point-to-site-connection-problems#solution you will never be able to connect. I think you need to triple check that you have followed the Microsoft troubleshooter that you posted to the letter including https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-certificates-point-to-site .

If it still doesn’t work I would try it on another computer and see if it is client related or not.